# Compiler Error __ZTVN13..6..E

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mosync

I'm currently struggeling with a compilerproblem. The problem is, that i use one of the MoSync example apps called "European Countries" (written in c++) to write my own. But when i compile the modified code, it gives me following error in response:

> Controller.cpp:24: Error: Unresolved symbol '__ZTVN13Flightmanager6FlightE',

I already had a look at the example several times and i already copied the code from the example to mine, but it doesn't solve any problems. 
In paticutlar i might understand what the error means (i do have c experience), but i've never seen such structured error. I also looked at namespacing conventions but there shouldn't be any problems.

//Flight.h

```
namespace Flightmanager
{

class Flight
{
    public:

    static int flightCounter;

    /**
     * The constructor creates the user interface.
     */

    Flight(char *flightnumber, char *gate, char *departure, char *additionalinfo, char *destinationairport, char *destinationairportshort) {

        this->_id = flightCounter;
        flightCounter ++;

        this->_flightnumber = flightnumber;
        this->_gate = gate;
        this->_departure = departure;
        this->_additionalinfo = additionalinfo;
        this->_destinationairport = destinationairport;
        this->_destinationairportshort = destinationairportshort;
    }

    virtual ~Flight();
}
```

//Controller.h

```
#include [all other includes]
#include "../Model/Flight.h"

namespace Flightmanager
    {
        Controller::Controller():
                mFlightArray(NULL),
                mCurrentlyShownScreen(NULL)
    {
    initScreenSizeConstants();
    initPlatformType();

//error: Unresolved symbol '__TZVN13Flightmanager6FlightE'.
        initData();
//error: Unresoled symbol '__TZVN13Flightmanager6Flight13flightCounterE'.
        mFlightTableView = new TableViewController(*this);//error: Unresoled symbol '__TZVN13Flightmanager6Flight13flightCounterE'.
        mFlightDetailView = new DetailViewController();
        }
    }
```

I use MoSync Version 3.2
Build date: 121219-1556

Thx

Comment: Well, *how* are you compiling the code?

Comment: Which compiler?  The interpretation of the mangled names depends on the compiler.

Comment: By using the mosync ide. Its an eclise derivate. I guess its a gnu C++ compiler (but not quite sure)

Comment: I think it's a *linker* error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link in something that has definitions for:

```
Flight::flightCounter

Flight::~Flight()
```

whether that's a `.o` object file for `Flight.cpp` (or some source file) or a library depends on your project.

Comment: Thx, you lead me in the right direction. All i needed to do was to implement the class information. Because i do also program in c# and java i didn't realize, that i needed to implement a class always in a cpp file. Thanks for your help!